# How to map a two argument function to a list?

Tags: clojure

I have a list of elements with some values in it.

I want to map it to a function and produce a list that contains, values computed by applying this two argument function to consecutive values in the first list.

This list will have one less element.

mapping function should take two arguments at a time.

**EDIT**

**Example**

the two argument function I am using is quite complex, so for simplicity lets assume it to be a function that calculated average of two numbers.

if I have a list: `[3 8 11 14 19 20 88]`.

Is it possible for me two write a function that maps my `average` function which for `(average 3 8)` will give  `5.5`

for `(average 8 11)` will give `9.5`

and `(average 11 14)` will give `12.5`

and so on...

on applying average to two consecutive values of the list at a time should give me.

```
[5.5 9.5 12.5 16.5 19.5 54.0]
```

as result.

map applies a single argument function to whole list and produces a new list with exactly same number of elements.

what I want is a way to apply my function which takes two arguments to take two consecutive at a time, apply my function to it and add the result to a new list.

Comment: Can you add some simple example?

Comment: Do you mean a reduce (http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduce)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it with map:

```
(map f coll (rest coll))
```

Comment: This works! How come map takes more than two arguments ? How does mapping work in this case ?
so it picks one argument from each list passed ?

until one of the list ends ?

Comment: `so it picks one argument from each list passed ? until one of the list ends ?` - Yes, exactly. The fn passed must take as many arguments as there are seqs passed to `map`.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar you can read more about `map` and other functions in [Clojure docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map).

Answer (score 7):

```
(fn [f coll] (map #(apply f %1) (partition 2 1 coll))
```

Go straight to 4clojure now!

Comment: Great! btw `#(apply f %1)` can be changed to `(partial apply f)`

Comment: Or just `#(reduce f %)`